# While True loop doesn't break after calling return

Tags: python, algorithm, function, while-loop

I'm trying to write a function that would take an integer, divide it into digits, sum them up, and if the sum is >=10, loop through the process until I get a single-digit sum. Could anyone tell me why my 'while True' loop isn't breaking:

```
def digital_root(n):
    while True:
        digits = []
        for i in str(n):
            digits.append(int(i))
        if sum(digits) < 10:
            return sum(digits)
```

I'm not really looking for an optimal solution, I just want to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: digits is reset every loop. You do the same thing every time.

Comment: You don't update `n` anywhere, so it repeats the same loop every time if the sum of digits is >= 10. The next iteration starts with an empty list and `str(n)` is still the original number, not the result of your previous iteration

Comment: I see that i reset the digits list every time, but my question is this:
If my n is 16, it would be divided into 1+6 = 7. Meaning that it should only loop once and break at my return statement. But for some reason it doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried running n=16? That works fine for me, because it will not need to loop more than one iteration. The issue will be with numbers that don't directly have a sum < 10.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It seems I am to blame here. 16 does work. Since there are several tests for this problem (first of which is when n=16), I assumed my function doesn't work since I was getting the time-out errors. What I failed to realise is that it times-out on other tests, thus not registering the fact that the first test was successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update the value of `n` in each iteration as follow:

```
def digital_root(n):
    while True:
        digits = []
        for i in str(n):
            digits.append(int(i))
        n = sum(digits)  # add
        if n < 10:
            return n
```